# Downsize Bootstrap buttons and input field's when viewport reaches certain width through utility classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap v4.4.1. at the time of writing and designing a form that uses `.btn` and `.input-group` classes. I would like to automatically downsize these fields and buttons when the viewport resizes to extra small (e.i. `576px` or less). In other words, I want the `.btn` to become as small as `.btn-sm` and `.input-group` to become as small as `.input-group-sm`. And no, I don't want to use the `.btn-sm` and `.input-group-sm` classes as is because I already like the normal size on larger screens. I just want these buttons and fields to be small only when the viewport is also small.

My current attempt is using media query and copying the style's of `.btn-sm` and `.input-group-sm` to their normal size counterparts (as demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabardelas/u9k0r253/12/)):

```
@media (max-width:576px) {
    /* These are from .btn-sm */
    .btn {
        padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
    }
    
    /* These are from .input-group-sm */
    .input-group > .custom-select,
    .input-group > .form-control:not(textarea) {
      height: calc(1.5em + 0.5rem + 2px);
    }
    
    .input-group > .custom-select,
    .input-group > .form-control,
    .input-group > .input-group-append > .btn,
    .input-group > .input-group-append > .input-group-text,
    .input-group > .input-group-prepend > .btn,
    .input-group > .input-group-prepend > .input-group-text {
       padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
       font-size: 0.875rem;
       line-height: 1.5;
       border-radius: 0.2rem;
    }

    .input-group > .custom-select {
       padding-right: 1.75rem;
    }
}
```

This could be messy and I potentially may mislook and skip copying some CSS attributes from the main bootstrap file. Are there any utility classes for this feature? I looked at the documentation and found none.